# ACF Single relationship link showing up as an array?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using ACF with flexible content and within that a relationship field to display a single link on the logo. I've set the maximum links to one, so don't need a loop to display multiple links, I just need the URL for one relationship link.

$clnk is the link and it needs to be displayed within the href tag, i.e.

```
<a href="' . $clnk . '"><img class="client_logos" src="' . $cl . '" alt="" /></a>
```

But the link itself is coming up as /Array ?

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<h2>Our clients</h2>

<div class="services_container" style="display: block;">

    <?php
    // check if the flexible content field has rows of data
    if (have_rows('clients')):

    // loop through the rows of data
    while (have_rows('clients')) : the_row();

        if (get_row_layout() == 'clients'):
            $tl = get_sub_field('client_group_name');

            echo '<h2>' . $tl . '</h2>';

        endif;

    // Check rows repeater
    echo '<div class="clients_container">';

    if( have_rows('client_details') ):

        // Loop through rows.
        while( have_rows('client_details') ) : the_row();

            // Load sub field value.
            $cl = get_sub_field('client_logo');
            $cn = get_sub_field('client_name');
            $clnk = get_sub_field('client_link');
            
            echo '<a href="' . $clnk . '"><img class="client_logos" src="' . $cl . '" alt="" /></a>';

        // End loop.
        endwhile;

    endif;

    echo '</div>';

    endwhile;

    endif;
    ?>

</div><!--clients container-->

</div>
```

EDIT - this was the final solution with code which detects which logos have links...

```
// Check rows repeater
if( have_rows('client_details') ):

    // Loop through rows.
    while( have_rows('client_details') ) : the_row();

        // Load sub field value.
        $cl = get_sub_field('client_logo');
        $cn = get_sub_field('client_name');

        $clnks = ( array ) get_sub_field( 'client_link' );
        $clnk  = array_pop( $clnks );

        //check if client links exist then add the tag
        if( have_rows('client_link') ):
            echo '<a href="' . (get_permalink( $clnk ))  . '"><img class="client_logos" src="' . $cl . '" alt="" /></a>';   
        endif;

        //if not just post the image
        if( !have_rows('client_link') ):
            echo '<img class="client_logos" src="' . $cl . '" alt="" />';
        endif;

        
    // End loop.
    endwhile;

endif;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [official documentation for Relationship fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/relationship/) indicates that it will always return an array of the selected posts.

Adjusting your code to expect an array is simple enough (untested):

```php
$clnks = ( array ) get_sub_field( 'client_link' );
$clnk  = array_pop( $clnks );

printf( '<a href="%s">', get_permalink( $clnk ) );
```

May want to consider changing the field type from Relationship to [Link](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/link/).

Comment: Thanks - I managed to get it working with a few quick edits